# SQLAlchemy Oracle can't insert characters with accents

Tags: oracle, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.5, cx-oracle

I've got a project based in `Flask` that uses a `Oracle` database and communicates trough `SQLAlchemy`and the `cx_Oracle` plugin. My problem is that I have a simple table with 2 `Strings`:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    description = Column(String(1024))
```

And when I try to save values with accents I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

In which de encode characters is different depending on the value of the text.

Here's an example of the values:

```
object = Example()
object.title = 'É its a character with accent'
object.description = 'Á another characters with accent'
db_session.add(object)
db_session.commit()
```

Do you have any idea what I can do to fix this? Some configuration?

Thanks :)

UPDATE:

As suggested I've tried 2 other ways:

class Example(Base):
    **tablename** = 'example'

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title = Column(Unicode(255))
description = Column(Unicode(1024))
```

And

class Example(Base):
    **tablename** = 'example'

```
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title = Column(String(255, convert_unicode=True))
description = Column(String(1024, convert_unicode=True))
```

Still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

that is because the names you are using, specially the accents are not in the ASCII table, please try to declare the title property as:

```
 title = Column(String(255, convert_unicode=True)
```

This may help, if not declare it as `Unicode` instead of `String`.
For more information you can also check the documentation here:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html

You should also ensure that on your `create_engine()` function you have the encoding optional param as "UTF-8" or "latin1" depending on the charset that you might need to be inputed. Of course "UTF-8" has everything you might actually need.

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Can you verify the type of string that is registered for that table?

Comment: Also what did you pass in the create_engine function, did you add a special encoding there?

Comment: `VARCHAR2(225 BYTE)`

Comment: No, I don't pass any special encoding, just the url for the connection.

Comment: The database is encoded in 'ISO885915` (I have no say in this matter)

Comment: on your create_engine do something like tke following: `create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@hostname/dbname",
                            encoding='UTF-8')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136573/discussion-between-patricia-and-gugas).